# Rotation in a Red Black tree

Tags: red-black-tree, tree-rotation

I am trying to figure out the rotation in a Red Black tree while its rebalancing is done. I understand why rotation is occurring but I don't get how it is being done. Also, what intermediate rotations like LL, RR , LR and RL are done to reach till the result and I would also appreciate if someone tells me any rule of thumb as to when to do any one of these rotation. Here is the rotation:

[image]

```
Rr(2) is the case when black node deficiency is in right child of "py" i.e. 
"y" and grandchild of "v" are 2 red nodes i.e. "b" and "x"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to understand rotations in Red Black Trees in a better way by breaking down the operation into different rotations. There are only 3 basic operations for a Left Leaning Red Black BST. The operations are performed in order as listed in this slide.

[image: Image demonstrating the rotations.]

Moreover, the Red Black Tree that you have shown is not correct as it violates the condition for a Red Black Tree. ie. Every path from the root to the leaf must have equal number of black edges. But in your final tree, the path from x to c has 2 black edges, while the path from x to a has 1 black edge. I recommend you to read more about self balancing BSTs and Red-Black BSTs from [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/33balanced/).

PS. I do not own the slide. It has been taken from Robert Sedgewick's course on Algorithms from coursera.